# Server down after PDO connection

Tags: mysql, php

I don't know is this off-topic for this site but I have site that run on PHP and MySQL. And I want to change my MySQL connection to PDO.

This is my connection file that I include in every file at the begining:

```
session_start();
$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
$database = @mysql_select_db("pemax", $connection) or die (mysql_error());
```

and I added this line for PDO connection:

```
$dbc = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pemax", "user", "password");
```

after adding this code I could not run any of my PHP from browser, so I had delete code I had added but still nothing just white blank page, and I don't receive any errors.

What could problem be?

This is the same topic on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406059/server-down-after-pdo-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but PDO function changed my permissions on connection file. Because of that, none of my files could be executed. I had installed script on another server and than I had noticed that my connection files ownership was changed. After I had changed ownership script start to work just fine. Thank you for your help.